# connect mysql database with visual studio 2012 error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: no)

Tags: mysql, exception, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to connect a mysql database with a visual studio windows form app but i have the error "Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: no)".
In my research in the internet most people say that this means that the password is wrong but when I create the connection and press test connection it appears to be connected

[See this image](http://prntscr.com/80p7vq)

below is the code in the form  load.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "user id=savvas;server=localhost;database=hoteldb;persistsecurityinfo=True";
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FAIL cause of " + e1.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and when i run it i have this MessageBox

http://prntscr.com/80p9b1

anyone can help? if something is wrong with with my post let me know :)

Comment: To specify a user/pass with the mysql connector see the 1st example @ http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: I think your connectionString is just missing the password?

Comment: thank you! i just added password =.. at connectionString. Some posts didnt mention this